# bootstrap tokenfiel delimiter '\n' (new line) copy and paste not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tokenfield

I wanna copy and paste a list of values separated by: '\n' like this:

123

234

234

in my boostrap tokenfield, but when I set the delimiter to: '\n' it doesn´t work .
this is my jquery configuration:

```
$('#res_pago').tokenfield({
    autocomplete :{
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                  type : "POST",
                  url : "api/getResponsablePago",
                  data : {myData: request.term},
                  success : function(result) {
                      console.log(result);
                      var datas = [];
                      if(result.data != undefined){
                          result.data.forEach(element => datas.push({ value: element.responsableID, label: element.responsableID + " - " + element.responsableDes}));
                      }
                      response(datas);
                  }
            });
            
        },
        delay: 800,
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
    delimiter: [',','\n']
});
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question in case it is useful for someone else in the future:

when I copy and paste a list separted by '\n' i don't now why the character '\n' is replaced by a simple space ' '.
considering this, the answer is simply add the character space to de delimiters list like this:

```
 delimiter: ['\n',' ', ',']
```

whole configuration for my example:

```
$('#res_pago').tokenfield({
    autocomplete :{
        source: function(request, response){
            $.ajax({
                  type : "POST",
                  url : "api/getResponsablePago",
                  data : {myData: request.term},
                  success : function(result) {
                      console.log(result);
                      var datas = [];
                      if(result.data != undefined){
                          result.data.forEach(element => datas.push({ value: element.responsableID, label: element.responsableID + " - " + element.responsableDes}));
                      }
                      response(datas);
                  }
            });
            
        },
        delay: 800,
    },
    showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
     delimiter: ['\n',' ', ',']
});
```